# SCNNode's convertTransform - Behind the scenes

Tags: scenekit, eigen

I'm trying to convert SCNNode's convertTransform to just Eigen but I'm clearly not getting what's going on behind the scenes.

```
let targetNodeTransform = targetNode?.convertTransform(transform, from: nil)
```

I'm using Eigen so I thought the transform's inverse would be the same. That doesn't seem to be the case, so what is happening in convertTransform when going from world coordinate space to object coordinate space? I'm looking for the math behind convertTransform so I can implement it using Eigen.

Comment: You're asking for the math behind `convertTransform`? Or you understand the math, but don't know how to phrase it in C++/Eigen?

Comment: Your update answers your question, unless you also wanted to write it in Eigen (sans the fact that I don't know what `worldTransform` is, I assume the origin and no rotation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Determined this is equivalent to the value returned by convertTransform above.

```
let targetNodeTransform = SCNMatrix4Mult(transform, SCNMatrix4Invert((targetNode?.worldTransform)!));
```

According to the documentation on SCNNode's worldTransform

> A world transform is the node’s coordinate space transformation
>   relative to the scene’s coordinate space. This transformation is the
>   concatenation of the node’s transform property with that of its parent
>   node, the parent’s parent, and so on up to the rootNode object of the scene.

Comment: Let's say I have  model structure like this  (ROOT) --> (Parent-CHILD) --> (CHILD1) , (CHILD2)

Here parent has 1 child - which has two child 

I have another node on the root node  let's say nodeX - 

so when I tried -` nodeX.convertTransfrom(SCNMatrixIdentity,(Parent-CHILD).transform )` 

it works only if (Parent-CHILD)  - scale is equal from all sides 
if (Parent-CHILD)  scale xyz is (2,2,4) transform is wrong 

Could you please suggest anything on this